# The -P switch does not seem to work for the tree command

Tags: command-line-interface

I'm using:

`tree . --prune --matchdirs -P dir-name`

which matches:

./directory/dir-name

but

`tree . --prune --matchdirs -P dir-*`

does not match.

Is there something wrong with the pattern?

I'm referring to https://manned.org/tree/11711706
but using MacOSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the pattern in single quotes?

`tree . --prune --matchdirs -P 'dir-*'`

Comment: `--prune` is the key when using `-P` and `--matchdirs`. tks

Answer (score 0):

You are not omitting dirs that are not matching even when using `--prune`.
`-P` does seems to work different than expected when using it with names on folders and the `--matchdirs` option.

From the 1.8.0 docs:

> --matchdirs:
>
> In the event of a match on the directory name, **matching is disabled for the  directory's contents**. If the --prune option is used, empty folders that match the pattern will not be pruned.

So **you include the non-matched dirs**, the difference is **only all matched dirs show all their content**.

--

### Example:

#### Content:

```
tree
.
├── abc
│   ├── foo.txt
│   └── xyz.txt
├── abc.txt
├── xyz
│   ├── abc.txt
│   └── bar.txt
└── xyz.txt

2 directories, 6 files
```

Matchdirs and prune on, still showing nonmatched folder.

```
tree -P "x*" --matchdirs --prune
.
├── abc
│   └── xyz.txt
├── xyz
│   ├── abc.txt
│   └── bar.txt
└── xyz.txt

2 directories, 4 files
```

Even though I used `--prune` and `--matchdirs` the folder which got no match is still shown. That is, because a file in the folder is matching the `-P` option.

#### Conclusion:

-P is not for including only folder names matching the string.